# How to parse dates in C?

Tags: c, date, parsing

I'm having trouble with one of my assignments for my C class, the objective is to read the dates from input, parse the dates, and have them output in the m/d/yyyy format. I have most of the code done but I don't know which functions to use to look for the dates and output it in the correct format. I didn't type a printf function yet because I've been trying to get the input first. I also commented out some of the input to show what I've been having trouble with. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int GetMonthAsInt(char *monthString) {
    int monthInt;

    if (strcmp(monthString, "January") == 0) {
        monthInt = 1;
    }
    else if (strcmp(monthString, "February") == 0) {
        monthInt = 2;
    }
    else if (strcmp(monthString, "March") == 0) {
        monthInt = 3;
    }
    else if (strcmp(monthString, "April") == 0) {
        monthInt = 4;
    }
    else if (strcmp(monthString, "May") == 0) {
        monthInt = 5;
    }
    else if (strcmp(monthString, "June") == 0) {
        monthInt = 6;
    }
    else if (strcmp(monthString, "July") == 0) {
        monthInt = 7;
    }
    else if (strcmp(monthString, "August") == 0) {
        monthInt = 8;
    }
    else if (strcmp(monthString, "September") == 0) {
        monthInt = 9;
    }
    else if (strcmp(monthString, "October") == 0) {
        monthInt = 10;
    }
    else if (strcmp(monthString, "November") == 0) {
        monthInt = 11;
    }
    else if (strcmp(monthString, "December") == 0) {
        monthInt = 12;
    }
    else {
        monthInt = 0;
    }

    return monthInt;
}

int main() {

    // TODO: Read dates from input, parse the dates to find the ones
   //       in the correct format, and output in m/d/yyyy format
   char month = NULL;
   char day = NULL;
   char year = NULL; 
   char date = NULL;
   char dateFormat[100];
   int mm;
   int i;
   
   while(1) {
    getchar(dateFormat[100], date);

   if(date == "-1")
     break;
     
  // int length = strlen(date); //
  // int dateFormat2 = date.(" ");  //
  //   month = .(mm); //
  //   day = date.; //
  //  year = date. //
  //  month = date; //
 //   mm = .(month); //

 
   if(date[length - 6] == ',' && mm > 0) {
     dateFormat[i++] = month + "//" + day + "//" + year;
    }
  }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hint: Not this way. Use a constant array of month names and spin through it in a loop. If you find it in index `n` then the month number is `n + 1`.

Comment: How are you passing [`getchar()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/getchar) any arguments? In your code `dateFormat[100]` does not exist, that's off the end of that array.

Comment: You should probably just [`fgets()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) a whole line, then parse through that however you see fit. A simple state machine is the usual approach.

Comment: One way of parsing dates is POSIX's [`strptime()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strptime.html).  This is almost the inverse of the C standard [`strftime()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strftime.html) function.  You should read the entire date field (line) and then consider parsing it with `strptime()`.  You can make multiple attempts with different format strings if necessary.  However, it isn't particularly easy to use — but it is a _lot_ easier than trying to roll your own.

Comment: While you can extract each component (day, month, year), you can only validate a date as a whole.  For example, Feb 31 2022 has valid components but is not a valid date.  Feb 29 2000 is good.  Feb 29, 2001 is not etc.

Comment: And if the year was 1712 and country was Sweden, then [30th February 1712](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_non-standard_dates#February_30) was a real date.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example implementation that Jonathan Leffler suggested above.  This assumes newline terminated dates, and I showed a couple of example formats (you may need to expand this to match your data):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

#define LEN 100

int main() {
    for(;;) {
        char s[LEN] = {0};
        fgets(s, LEN, stdin);
        if(!strcmp(s, "-1"))
            break;
        const char *formats[] = {
            "%h %d, %Y",
            "%m/%d/%Y",
        };
        struct tm tm = { 0 };
        for(unsigned i = 0; i < sizeof(formats) / sizeof(*formats); i++) {
            char *s2 = strptime(s, formats[i], &tm);
            if(s2 && *s2 == '\n') {
                // or use strftime()
                printf("%u/%u/%u\n",
                    tm.tm_mon + 1,
                    tm.tm_mday,
                    tm.tm_year + 1900
                );
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Consider printing out failed dates, say, to stderr, so you can tweak your formats.

Comment: You should probably avoid cross-contamination of results by setting `tm` to all zeroes on each iteration — `struct tm tm = { 0 };` defined inside the loop, before the call to `strptime()`.  OTOH, working with just the date fields, cross-contamination (values set by the previous conversion) are less likely to be a problem.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Done.  Wouldn't strptime() set all fields on success?

Comment: If you don't supply an hour value in string, then `tm_hour` won't be set.  I have a program which exercises `strptime()` — it's called `strptime`.  It takes the time string and a format string and calls `strptime()`, but then calls `mktime()` to normalize the values and produce a `time_t` answer.  (It spends an inordinate amount of code disambiguation an error return from `mktime()` and a value `1969-12-31 23:59:59Z`, too — both have the numeric representation `-1`!).  Then it matters more — with your date-only conversions, it is less critical.

Comment: Samples: `strptime '2022-07-29 18:23:45'` — `1659144225 = 2022-07-29 18:23:45`; `TZ=UTC0 strptime '2022-07-29 18:23:45'` — `1659119025 = 2022-07-29 18:23:45`; `TZ=UTC0 strptime -T '%d %B %Y %H.%M.%S' '29 July 2022 18.23.45'` —
`1659119025 = 29 July 2022 18.23.45`; `TZ=UTC0 strptime '1969-12-31 23:59:59'` — `-1 = 1969-12-31 23:59:59`.  That's different from what you're attempting to do, so don't be worried about it.  I didn't post my code last night because although it's not a big program, it is still over 100 lines because of the option parsing and so on.